# How to set height div css for 16:9 aspect ratio in portrait mode for Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, ionic-framework

Suppose I have a div that is on top of the ion-content. I'm trying to set the height of the div by getting the width of the device and calculate it so that the aspect ratio is 16:9 just like the youtube app. However, I have no idea how to achieve it using css. For now, this is what I have.

```
div {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 40%; <-- how to set this height so that it is 16:9 
    background: black;

div.img {
    width: 360px;
    max-height: 202.5px;
}
```

[image]

What I wanted:

[image]

Comment: **16:9** That's means You need `height` `width` ratio like this ?

Comment: width of div 16 (100% of screen width) : height of div 9

Comment: Just take my answer it solved by css

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use this simple css Style

**56.25%**  = 16:9 Aspect Ratio

```
.img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 56.25vw;
}
```

Comment: I see the concept here but isn't that the whole view height of the page? Can you do the same but in relation to the container div? I have my pictures scaling great with just 100% width, but if a picture is missing the height is set to the same value as the width without a height value set.

Answer (score 0):

First: your source images need be 16:9.
Than you can as simply as :

```
div {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 40%;
    background: black;

div.img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Of course if that *css* corresponds to a properly nested `<div><img...></div>` structure.

Comment: this distorts my image if it's too large. How may I fit the image?

Comment: But you are getting the constant 16:9 image ratio aren't you?
You can also replace the `max-height: 40%` with `height: 40%` on your div.
Browser will re-sample large images good enough, some will do better, others, no so satisfying - but you should give some regard to your user bandwidth and make them smaller.

Answer (score 0):

¿Can you set the image as background-image? In that case you could use this:

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header" style="background-image: url(https://placehold.it/1200x600)">
  </div>
  <div class="content">Content here</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 960px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 56%;
  background-color: rgba(#f00,0.1);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

Here you can see it in action: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBYeVE?editors=1100)

Hope it helps!!